# One word for "not allowed to do things"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am making a precis. I have a sentence here.

```
A child feels sad when he is not allowed to do things on its will.
```

How can I replace sentence with a single word. "**not allowed to do things on will**"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To act or [behave](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/behave) freely or independently*, may replace your sentence

> To conduct oneself in a specified way: The child behaved badly at the par
>
> - A child feels sad when he can't behave freely.

Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com